# How to terminate old session in iTerm2

Tags: php, session, localhost, iterm2

Maybe a stupid question with an obvious answer, but I don't know the solution. I'm new with the command line and especially Apple and iTerm2.

In iTerm2 I open a new session for my PHP project with `php -S localhost:port`

Now I accidentally closed this tab once and now I don't know how to terminate that session.
When I want to open another project on that port (`8000`) it says, ofcourse, `Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000 (reason: Address already in use)`

Can someone help me on how to terminate this session, so I can start another project on this port instead of using 8001, 8002, 8003 etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fixed it myself, but since I can't be the only one wondering this, here is my solution:

Enter this into the terminal:

```
lsof -i TCP:8000
```

It will yield a result that might look something like this:

```
renaebair@siren ~/workspace/intridea/newsite (master) 
→ lsof -i TCP:3000
COMMAND  PID   USER       FD     TYPE     DEVICE     SIZE/OFF    NODE   NAME
ruby   68780   renaebair   6u    IPv4     0x10898278     0t0      TCP     *:hbci (LISTEN)
```

Grab the process number (a.k.a. PID) (in this case it was 68780) and then type `“kill #{that_pid}”`:

```
kill 68780
```

Then try restarting your server and all should be well!

Answer (score 1):

I think that this might work, at least in my unix machine it does.

```
sudo kill $(fuser -n tcp 8000 2> /dev/null)
```